# How pass values into web service using JSON

Tags: android, json

I am new in android.Currently i am working in web service.But this time i got one problem.I want to pass values into server using json.The JSOn array is in this form.

`{"request":{"api_key":"valid api key", "action":"register", "firstName":"aromal",   "lastName":"chekavar",             "email":"aromal@mstcochin.com", "address":"test address", "city":"test city", "state":"test state", "dob":"2008-06-26", "gender":"Male", "zipCode":"123456", "pin":"1234", "deviceId":"valid device id", "gcmRegId":"111111","country":"5"
}}`

Please help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
        jobj.put("api_key", valiapikey);
        jobj.put("action", register);
        ...............................
        request.put("request", jobj);
```

Create a JSON object(jobj here) enclosing all your parameters with their keys and then enclose it in "request" JSON object.